# How to adjust an UIButton's imageSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

How can I adjust the image size of the UIButton? I am setting the image like this:

```
[myLikesButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-heart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However this fills up the image to the full button, how do I make the image smaller?

---

*Historic note:*

For this now 10+ yr old question, you now typically just set the point size using `setPreferredSymbolConfiguration`

Comment: @CodaFi is right, you should generally provide assets at the right size as it reduces any work for the CPU, uses less memory and will most likely look better as you do not potentially introduce any scaling artefacts...

Comment: Also you can make the button to the size of image (or vice-versa).Why have have a big button ...with a small image in it.Simply add the image you want , that's what custom buttons are for or you can explain the logic you want to implement for others to have a clear idea.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need to play with the buttons image edge inset.  Something like:

```
myLikesButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30)
```

Comment: just fyi, it will not change the real width of an uibutton's imageview, so, it will not make fix problem with buttons where you need title and image

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 15. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328038/imageedgeinsets-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0

Comment: imagePadding is the padding beside the image and the button text, totally unrelated.

Comment: Also it's slightly deprecated, read the documentation. It says "This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration".

Answer (score 121):

Tim's answer is correct, however I wanted to add another suggestion, because in my case there was a simpler solution altogether.

I was looking to set the `UIButton` image insets because I didn't realize that I could set the content mode on the button's `UIImageView`, which would have prevented the need to use UIEdgeInsets and hard-coded values altogether. Simply access the underlying imageview on the button and set the content mode:

```
myButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

See [UIButton doesn't listen to content mode setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950613/uibutton-doesnt-listen-to-content-mode-setting)

**Swift 3**

```
myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: how to do same for backgroundImage?

Comment: @Andrea.Ferrando `button.backgroundImageView.contentMode` doesn't work

Comment: Save yourself some time and make sure you are setting image not background image! @SeongLee is correct you can't manipulate background image with contentMode or EdgeInserts

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Answer (score 103):

Swift :

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkmark_white"), for: .normal)
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. I created a PDF icon within Inkscape and the `contentVerticalAlignment/contentHorizontalAlignment` options got enabled me to scale it the way I was hoping to. Thank you for posting this.

Comment: setting `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment` did the trick

Comment: This solution works great when using PDF assets for icons. Thank you!

Comment: contentVerticalAlignment and contentHorizontalAlignment did work to me, whose UIImageView was too small in UIButton.

Comment: ...thus also working perfectly fine for System Icons / SF Symbols – thanks!

Answer (score 68):

Here is the other solution to scale an imageView of UIButton.

```
button.imageView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
```

Comment: You saved my day. I just wanted to scale my image inside a button. No insets no nothing, thanks!

Comment: Manually setting image insets caused problems when sizing my button/text. This solution worked best dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I think this is a best answer.

Comment: Oh my, that really helped! I tried all the solutions above this one. Thank you!

Comment: Its working, explain how exactly CATransform3DMakeScale works..

Comment: Genius! Simplest and easiest solution ever!

Answer (score 48):

You can also do that from inteface builder like this.

[image]

I think it's helpful.

Answer (score 46):

If your image is too large (and you can't/don't want to just made the image smaller), a combination of the first two answers works great.

```
addButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
addButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 5.0)
```

Unless you get the image insets just right, the image will be skewed without changing the `contentMode`.

Comment: .imageEdgeInsets is deprecated. UIButton.Configuration should be used.

Answer (score 24):

you can use `imageEdgeInsets` property
The inset or outset margins for the rectangle around the button’s image.

```
 [self.btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
```

A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge.

Answer (score 16):

Heres the Swift version:

```
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Comment: just fyi, it will not change the real width of an uibutton's imageview, so, it will not make fix problem with buttons where you need title and image

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **symbolic images** for the button, then this solution is better:

```
button.setPreferredSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 48), forImageIn: .normal)
```

Comment: iOS 15, XCode 14.2 this worked great!

Comment: Awesome thx!  iOS 16 Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 13):

Insetting the image works for me, but I also needed the button Type to be Custom and the button Style to be Default.  The defaults for a button added in Xcode 13 are System for Type and Plain for Style.

```
self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3.0, left: 3.0, bottom: 3.0, right: 3.0)
```

[image]

Comment: That work perfect ...

Comment: It's rather tricky to set the TYPE and STYLE ***in code***.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72913591/294884

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

You would need to use these two lines of code, in this specific order. All you need is to change the top and bottom value of the edge insets.

```
addButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
addButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: These caused an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when called from `override func layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 7):

With the help of [Tim C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10576708/2767207), I was able to create an extension on `UIButton` using Swift that allows you to specify the image frame by using the `.setImage()` function with an extra `frame` parameter

```
extension UIButton{

    func setImage(image: UIImage?, inFrame frame: CGRect?, forState state: UIControlState){
        self.setImage(image, forState: state)

        if let frame = frame{
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
                top: frame.minY - self.frame.minY,
                left: frame.minX - self.frame.minX,
                bottom: self.frame.maxY - frame.maxY,
                right: self.frame.maxX - frame.maxX
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Using this, if you wanted to set the frame of a `UIButton` to `CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)`, and set the image of it to `myImage` with a frame of `CGRectMake(8, 8, 48, 48)`, you could use

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64))
button.setImage(
    myImage,
    inFrame: CGRectMake(8, 8, 48, 48),
    forState: UIControlState.Normal
)
```

Comment: You should `if let` instead of checking if `frame` is `nil` and then [force unwrapping a zillion times](https://i.imgflip.com/utfq7.jpg).

Answer (score 7):

When changing icon size with 
`UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`, keep in mind button dimensions and the ability of UIEdgeInsetsMake to work with negative values as if they are positive.

Example: Two buttons with height 100 and aspect 1:1.

```
left.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 40, 0)
right.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 40, 0)
```

[image]

```
left.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 40, 0)
right.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 0, 45, 0)
```

[image]

```
left.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 40, 0)
right.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 60, 0)
```

[image]

Examples 1 and 3 are identical since ABS(100 - (40 + 40)) = ABS(100 - (60 + 60))

Answer (score 5):

**Updated for Swift > 5**

set the size:

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
```

---

set margins:

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to resize the UIImage in code like the following. Note: this code only scales by height, but you can easily adjust the function to scale by width as well.

```
let targetHeight = CGFloat(28)
let newImage = resizeImage(image: UIImage(named: "Image.png")!, targetHeight: targetHeight)
button.setImage(newImage, for: .normal)

fileprivate func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    // Get current image size
    let size = image.size

    // Compute scaled, new size
    let heightRatio = targetHeight / size.height
    let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Create new image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Return new image
    return newImage!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

I set myButton width and height to 40 and my padding from EdgeInsetsMake is 15 all sides. I suggest to add a background color to your button to see the actual padding.

```
myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray // sample color to check padding
myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
yourButtonName.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to play around with image insets and you are using auto layout (which I assume you do), another solution is to add size constraints to the image view. Make sure the constraints have a priority of 999, otherwise auto layout will complain.

```
guard let imageView = button.imageView else { return }

let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
let sizeConstraints = [
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width),
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
]
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
sizeConstraints.forEach { $0.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: priority) }
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(sizeConstraints)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score -6):

i think, your image size is also same as button size then you put image in background of the button like :

```
[myLikesButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-heart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

you mast have same size of image and button.i hope you understand my point.