# 'imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting the warning:

```
'imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0
```

When setting UIButton imageEdgeInsets like so:

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

I tried setting imageEdgeInsets like so:

```
UIImage(named: "filter")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
```

Both where top, left, right and bottom are positive or negative values, no luck. Anyone who knows the version of

```
imageEdgeInsets
```

That's not deprecated in iOS 15?
All help is appreciated,
Kind regards :)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved with using a non-system image? I cannot figure out a way to make a non-system image scale to the size of the button but with image insets.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

iOS 15 Apple introduced 3 new options to control padding and insets.

1. `.titlePadding` : Padding between the title and subtitle labels.
2. `.imagePadding` : Padding between the button’s image and text.
3. `.contentInsets`: Padding from the button’s content area to its bounds.

Using the above option you can manage and set your button style according.

[image]

You can check this [article](https://sarunw.com/posts/new-way-to-style-uibutton-in-ios15/#insets-%2F-padding) for more. [Source and Image](https://sarunw.com/posts/new-way-to-style-uibutton-in-ios15/#insets-%2F-padding)

So your code should be like this

```
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
configuration.title = "Title"
configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "swift")
configuration.titlePadding = 10
configuration.imagePadding = 10
configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, I just can't get it to work with non-system images. When I use a huge image from my assets, it doesn't size properly, no matter UIButton.Configuration or buttonSize. Help with this would really be appreciated! (Hopefully the solution is not a padding of 500 or resizing of the image)

Comment: I think you have to resize the image or set some size to UIButton. before iOS 15 also not possible maybe.

Comment: This fix does the trick, but applying a .configuration seems to knock out the font settings for the UIButton. Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Hey, I applied the same method to my Button's title and it's working fine when I first load up the app but the font size gets bigger when I tap the button or present another view controller. Any help?

Comment: Does it mean if we don't provide a configuration the deprecated properties still work? Is there a way to suppress the warning? Thank you!

Comment: @hyouuu that's what I'm asking myself, too. I haven't yet found a way to get rid of the default content inset when using the new button configuration. However, I have a button that I want to completely fill with an image. This does not seem to be possible when using the configuration...

Comment: @SamuraiSteve On my guess, you might not stop it, but you can set it in the configuration as: ```myButton.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in 
                var outcoming = incoming
                outcoming.font = UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 16)
                return outcoming
            }```

Comment: Unfortunately the `contentInsets` isn't applied to the image on its own, so this isn't actually a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 11):

Swift now comes default with different types of buttons that you can setup up from iOS 15 onwards. Use `UIButton.Configuration` to set up your button. For your case, you can use,

```
config.imagePadding = 5
```

An example can be seen below:

```
var filled = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
filled.title = "Filled button"
filled.buttonSize = .large
filled.subtitle = "With subtitle even"
filled.image = UIImage(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
filled.imagePlacement = .trailing
filled.imagePadding = 5

let button = UIButton(configuration: filled, primaryAction: nil)
```

[image]

Image and Code credits to [nemecek.be](https://nemecek.be/blog/107/big-improvements-to-uibutton-in-ios-15)

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you so much, I do have a problem though. When I use a huge image from my assets, it doesn't size properly, no matter UIButton.Configuration or buttonSize. Help with this would really be appreciated! (Hopefully the solution is not a padding of 500 or resizing of the image) :)

Comment: I don't think so. Try `button.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill/scaleAspectFit`

Comment: Try resizing the image?

Comment: Yes, thanks I will! Thanks again for taking the time, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the original/legacy layout of UIButton and wish to suppress the associated warnings in the Xcode Issue navigator, you can use Key-Value Coding (KVC).

Here's an example of a property wrapper for imageEdgeInsets:

```
public var imageEdgeInsetsIgnoreDeprecated: UIEdgeInsets {
    get {
        return value(forKey: "imageEdgeInsets") as! UIEdgeInsets
    }
    set {
        setValue(newValue, forKey: "imageEdgeInsets")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly easier fixed, just for this issue:

```
myButton.configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)

//or just imagePadding in the case above:
myButton.configuration?.configuration?.imagePadding = 10
```