# 'titleEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift, button, uikit, ios15

I am getting warning:

`'titleEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration`

I want to give padding to button.

I have tried following code for giving padding.

`btnPassword.configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)`
But it's not working.

Here ['imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328038/imageedgeinsets-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0) is similar question/s asked previously, but it's not helping me out.

Can anyone knows the solution for iOS 15.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But it's not working.... Please specify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use button configuration iOS 15 onwards :

```
private func makeButton(withTitle title: String) -> UIButton {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    configuration.title = title
    configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .blue
    configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16)
    
    button.configuration = configuration
    
    return button
}
```

You can simply call this method while creating your button as given below:

```
let button = makeButton(withTitle: "Get Started")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
btnPassword.configuration?.titlePadding = 10