# 'adjustsImageWhenDisabled' was deprecated in iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hey i get this Warning in my code and want to resolve it but i find no solution:

'adjustsImageWhenDisabled' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration, you may customize to replicate this behavior via a configurationUpdateHandler

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve the warning?

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: *"This property is ignored when using **UIButtonConfiguration*** ... so, you can still use it with a `UIButton` if you are *not* using configuration.

Comment: Relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328038/imageedgeinsets-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0 because it relates to legacy layout of UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up a `ConfigurationUpdateHandler` where you should switch between your button states to set up your button's imageView's `tintAdjustmentMode`.

```
btn.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        switch button.state {
            case .disabled:
                button.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode = .dimmed
                break
            default:
                button.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
                break
        }
    }
```