# How do I fix ImageEdgeInsets deprecated in iOS 15.0 when the padding needs to be different on each side?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, deprecated

So `imageEdgeInsets` has been depricated in `iOS 15`. Right now the code looks like this:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    init(title: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = .blue
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
        
        // This is depricated
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 40)
        
        configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16)
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("Button tapped!")
    }
}
```

I was looking for a solution and sort of found one here:

['imageEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328038/imageedgeinsets-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0)

Apparently we are supposed to use `configuration?.imagePadding` instead. So instead of `configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16)` we should use `configuration?.imagePadding = 0`.

I think you can already spot the issue: `configuration?.imagePadding` only takes a single `CGFloat` so if you want to have different padding on different sides like this: `NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16)` you're out of luck.

So how do I get away from the deprecation while retaining different padding for all sides?

*** Note ***
The issue is the same for `titleEdgeInsets`

Also, after using `configuration?.imagePadding` it seems to do absolutely nothing while `NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16)` works like a charm.

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with a picture of the button you are trying to create? it's not clear if you have a button with just an image or a button with both title and image. If both, what actual arrangement do you want? A picture will help to clarify your question a lot.

Comment: Sure, I added it. But it's just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement is a combination of the `placement` of the image

```
configuration?.imagePlacement = .leading
```

and the distance between the image and the text

```
configuration?.imagePadding = 12.0
```

- `imagePlacement` specifies the position of the image relative to the text.
- `imagePadding` specifies the distance between the image and the text.
- `contentInsets` specifies the distance of image and text to the edges of the button.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! But what if you want to set multiple paddings? setting imagePlacement to .trailing then setting padding there as well?