# iOS >> UIButton ImageView Property >> How to set Content Mode?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, contentmode

Is there a way to set a UIButton Image, BackgroundImage or ImageView Properties Content Mode Property?

I've tried the direct approach (it didn't work, of course...):

```
self.imageButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

It's nice to have a button with an image, but if there's no way to set it properly, it's not very handy...

Comment: "The value of the property is nil for system buttons." from Apple Development library.

Comment: Another way I have approached such problems in the past is to create a UIImageView, add my picture in it and then on top of UIImageView I add a custom blank UIButton. When user touches the image, he's actually touching the button. That way I have more control over image and its properties.

Answer (score 32):

Using iOS7/8 with auto-layout, `button.imageView` doesn't get scaled when `button` is laid out, e.g. for iPhone 6:

```
(lldb) po button
<UIButton: 0x7fb4f501d7d0; frame = (0 0; 375 275); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 102; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb4f501d160>>

(lldb) po button.imageView
<UIImageView: 0x7fb4f51d21f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb4f5152860>>
```

After setting `button`'s image, `button.imageView` assumed the size of the image, e.g. for a 320x240 image:

```
(lldb) po button.imageView
<UIImageView: 0x7fb4f51d21f0; frame = (27.5 17.5; 320 240); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb4f5152860>>
```

It looks like `button.imageView` does not respect its content mode, but actually, it is the size of the `button.imageView` that is the problem.

**The answer is to set `button`'s content alignment as well.**

The following sets `button`'s image, sets `button.imageView`'s content mode, and makes `button.imageView` fit the size of `button`:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
```

Now, `button.imageView` is the same size as `button`, **and** has the desired content mode.

```
(lldb) po button.imageView
<UIImageView: 0x7faac219a5c0; frame = (0 0; 375 275); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faac219a6c0>>
```

The desired result is thereby achieved. Very handy!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when setting a separate image for UIControlStateHighlighted

Comment: set content mode to 'scale to fill' on image view and h & v alignments to 'fill' on the button. works in xamarin as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to subclass UIButton than you can try this,

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    for (UIView *view in button.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every UIButton has one hidden UIImageView of its own. So we have to set the content mode like the way given below...

```
[[btn imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```