# UIButton child ImageView does not respect scale aspect fit content mode

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I have a `UIButton` with constraints of 64x64px and a larger child `ImageView` (155px) that does not scale to fit within the 64x64 parent button. Relevant properties:

- `UIButton` is of type `custom`
- `UIButton` `contentVerticalAlignment` and `contentHorizontalAlignment` is set to `fill`
- `UIButton` content mode is `scaleToFill`
- Child `ImageView`'s content mode is set to `scaleAspectFit` like below (all above properties I set with the attributes pane in interface builder):

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        if let imageView = button.imageView {
            print("There is an image view", imageView.contentMode.rawValue) // Prints 1 since we set scale aspect fit above
        } else {
            print("There is NO image view")
        }
    }

// Rest of class, truncated for brevity

}
```

There are many other questions posted on SO (like [UIButton doesn't listen to content mode setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950613/uibutton-doesnt-listen-to-content-mode-setting)) and I've tried all the solutions with no luck.

I'm running Xcode version 13.0, not sure if something has changed in recent versions of Swift/Xcode or if I'm just missing something simple. Would really appreciate any ideas from the SO community. Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer in the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439301/uibutton-image-behavior-changed-in-ios-15 above, just confirming that for anyone who lands here. Thanks so much whoever linked me to that, you're fantastic.

Comment: Okay, but how do you do this with code? There is no `UIButton.ButtonType` case called `default`